# Pass data from ViewController to SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

How pass data from **ViewController** to **SwiftUI View** up to date every time ?

**Problem:**
So actually I can pass data but I have problem with the update of the data.

I want to interfacing with UIKit in my SwiftUI Project which need to use the back camera to create a Color Picker.
The variable which store the Color is every time update in my ViewController but when I want to pass this data in my ContentView through the ViewControllerWrapper the value of the variable is update when I close and open back my app.

***What I actually do:***

> **Content View:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var color: UIColor = UIColor.clear

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color("c2").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    CameraView(color: $color)
                    DockView(color: $color)
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Image(systemName: "circle.grid.hex").font(.system(size: 28)).foregroundColor(Color("c1")))
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> (CameraView) **View Controller:**

```
struct CameraView: View {
    
    @Binding var color: UIColor


    var body: some View {
        ViewControllerWrapper(color: $color)
    }
}

struct ViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController
    
    @Binding var color: UIColor
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) -> ViewController {
        let v = ViewController()
        return v
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) {
        color = uiViewController.color
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var currentDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: WIDTH/2-4, y:WIDTH/2-4)
    
    var color: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
        guard let baseAddr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0) else {
            return
        }
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bimapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = [
            .byteOrder32Little,
            CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)]
        
        guard let content = CGContext(data: baseAddr, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bimapInfo.rawValue) else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let cgImage = content.makeImage() else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.previewLayer.contents = cgImage
            
            self.color = self.previewLayer.pickColor(at: self.center)!
            
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame
            self.lineShape.strokeColor = self.color.cgColor
            self.lineShape2.fillColor = self.color.cgColor
            self.label.text = "#\(self.hexFromUIColor(color: self.color))"
        }
        
    }
    
    let previewLayer = CALayer()
    let lineShape = CAShapeLayer()
    let lineShape1 = CAShapeLayer()
    let lineShape2 = CAShapeLayer()
    let lineShape3 = CAShapeLayer()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    func setupUI() {
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame
        
        
        previewLayer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        previewLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)))
        view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        
        //Cercle
        let linePath = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        lineShape.frame = CGRect.init(x: WIDTH/2-20, y:WIDTH/2-20, width: 40, height: 40)
        lineShape.lineWidth = 5
        lineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        lineShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(lineShape, at: 1)
        
        //Point
        let linePath1 = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8, height: 8))
        lineShape1.frame = CGRect.init(x: WIDTH/2-4, y:WIDTH/2-4, width: 8, height: 8)
        lineShape1.path = linePath1.cgPath
        lineShape1.fillColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(lineShape1, at: 1)
        
        //Preview
        let linePath2 = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
        lineShape2.frame = CGRect.init(x: WIDTH/2-70, y:120, width: 25, height: 25)
        lineShape2.path = linePath2.cgPath
        lineShape2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(lineShape2, at: 1)
        
        //Container
        let linePath3 = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50), cornerRadius: 25)
        lineShape3.frame = CGRect.init(x: WIDTH/2-80, y:107, width: 150, height: 30)
        lineShape3.path = linePath3.cgPath
        lineShape3.fillColor = UIColor(named: "c3")?.cgColor
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(lineShape3, at: 1)
        
        
        //Label
        label.frame = CGRect.init(x: WIDTH/2-35, y:120, width: 100, height: 21)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        label.tintColor = UIColor(named: "c1")
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        self.CreateUI()
    }
    
  
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.camera.video.queue")
    
    
    func CreateUI(){
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080

        self.currentDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoOutput.videoSettings = ([kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable: NSNumber(value: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA)] as! [String : Any])
            videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
            
            if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                self.captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            }
            self.captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    func hexFromUIColor(color: UIColor) -> String{
        let hexString = String(format: "%02X%02X%02X",
        Int(color.cgColor.components![0]*255.0),
        Int(color.cgColor.components![1]*255.0),
        Int(color.cgColor.components![2]*255.0))
        return hexString
    }
    
    
}
```

If you have idea how to get the value up to data in my ContentView.

Thanks.